# Spring Boot REST Controller doesn't work after setting attribute with custom xml bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am learning Spring framework (more generally Java EE).

I like the feature of passing the configuration using xml files. I started by the [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) example and it worked fine.

The only problem is that once I add my custom xml configuration with beans to set the attribute value inside the controller it doesn't work anymore, in the server log file it says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.controller.FirstController#0' bean method (...)` then it lists all the methods in the controller exactly like if I defined multiple methods with identical RequestMapping (which is not the case).

I wanted to set a single attribute, but it seems that because of that the entire autoconfiguration doesn't work anymore.

### Before

Main class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("first")
public class FirstController {
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test() {
        log.info("Test");
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

### After

Main class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:config.xml")
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("first")
public class FirstController {
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private String testingbean;
    public void setTestingbean(String testingbean) {
        this.testingbean = testingbean;
    }

    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test() {
        log.info("Test");
        return "OK";
    }

    @RequestMapping("beantest")
    public String testBeans() {
        return testingbean;
    }
}
```

Config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- test bean -->
    <bean class="com.example.controller.FirstController">
        <property name="testingbean" value="works"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the `Before` version after accessing /first/test it returned `OK`, now I get blank page and `Ambiguous mapping found` error in the log file.

Could someone explain to me how to mix Spring Boot autoconfiguration with custom defined beans?

Comment: Why are you using XML? Just define an `@Bean` in an `@Configuration` class or define an `@Component` in an `@CompomentScan` location. Incidentally, there's a new [`@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) annotation that can replace a few of the standard annotations.

Comment: This way will I be able to load String from files I store in ressources directory etc? (this is my goal, I know how to do it but only using xml configuration) I am trying to avoid very big sources files, my application will use a lot of Strings

Comment: I don't understand. If you need to load properties files, use a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html). If you need configuration properties, consider using [externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). If  you need i18n, then this is a different question entirely.

Comment: how does `AdminController` looks like??

Comment: @BoristheSpider, let's say I externalize the configuration using .properties files, does it give exactly the same features like xml beans? I ask because for xml beans I have plenty of examples on the internet, however for properties not so many.

Comment: @sodik, AdminController is FirstController, I just forgot to rename it before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would also recommend to use property files to externalize configuration if possible.

EDIT: Spring boot provides fine documentation on that [topic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

2. The problem can be the combination of XML configuration and default component scan - the same bean can be defined twice. If this is the case consider "manual" exclude via http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--

Comment: I would like to ask the same question as I asked to BoristheSpider, let's say I externalize the configuration using .properties files, does it give exactly the same features like xml beans? I ask because for xml beans I have plenty of examples on the internet, however for properties not so many.

Comment: For example I have no idea how to complete this tutorial http://simplespringtutorial.com/resourceinjection.html without any xml...

Comment: in java config you can do what you want. you can simply pass the path to resource as string and then create resource from it like here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Comment: But then the path would have to be hardcoded in the source and changing it would require recompiling entire application. I wanted to either have it precised in xml, either in .properties file, either make it somehow autowired (I don't know if it's possible, lets say while constructing it couldautomatically choose file path from initialized attribute name).

Comment: not at all. use e.g. `@Value` and boot `application.properties` - see the link I have already provided in answer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config !

Comment: Yes, I did look it up, the problem is that it doesn't solve the problem because of the following reason.
Let's say, I have a FileProvider class, in which there is a String filename attribute with Value annotation. Then in controller class I have separate instance of FileProvider as attributes (one per file). In this case Value does not solve the problem, because each instance of FileProvider will contain same file, not DIFFERENT file. It doesn't help, except if there is a possibility to make Value be dependant on which class instancies this object on which attribute.

Comment: It's not really clear how I explained it... I'm trying to replace the `<constructor-arg>` from xml configuration with something that can be stored in application.properties.

Comment: this looks quite unrelated to this question.... maybe try to ask new question with the problems you have. if you want to create more beans (of the same class), and that is fixed numbers - use java config instead and provide proper values for each definition, if you want list of beans, properties can contain "collections" of values. However I highly recommend you to also describe WHY do you want it, since maybe there is better solution (and I would not consider editing XML config outside of app as good solution).